# AWS: Error accessing the Internet with a custom Network ACL

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, routing

I've been stuck looking at my screen for about 2 hours trying to figure out why this is not working. I'm building the typical VPC with a private and public subnet and trying to lock it down as much as possible. I have a few security groups, but I know the issue is in the NACL, as if I relax the rules, everything works.

My inbound NACL is
[image: Inbound ACL]

and the outbound is
[image]

The problem I have is that I cannot access the internet (port 80 and 443) from inside any of the EC2 instances in either the public or private subnets. I know the "problem rule" is inbound no 1000, which allows all ephemeral ports from `10.0.0.0/16`. If I change this rule to apply to all sources (`0.0.0.0/0`) I can access the internet from all ec2 instances in both subnets (I'm testing this by running different apps; curl and yum mostly.

I'm just struggling to understand this behaviour, as the inbound rule should allow any ec2 instance to open an ephemeral port and talk to the router, and then the router can talk to port 80 and 443 of any host. I have the feeling I'm missing simple, but crucial point here :).

### edit

In ascii art, this is my understanding of the rules

```
EC2 instance does a curl on www.google.com (port 80) 

SYN Packet out to stablish the connection (ephemeral port on VM to port 80)
EC2 vm (somewhere in 10.0.0.0/16:ephemeral)
 -> SG 
 -> NACL in (in rule 1000 - ALLOW source 10.0.0.0/16 on ports 1024-65535) 
 -> NACL out (out rule 200 - ALLOW destination 0.0.0.0/0 on port 80)
 -> IGW 
 -> Google (172.217.23.14:80)

SYN + ACK Packet in to continue the connection handshake
Google (172.217.23.14:80)
  -> IGW 
  -> NACL in (in rule 100 - ALLOW source 0.0.0.0/0 on port 80) 
  -> NACL out (out rule 100 - ALLOW destination 0.0.0.0/0 on port 1024-65535) 
  -> SG 
  -> EC2 vm (somewhere in 10.0.0.0/16:ephemeral)
```

### Edit 2

Running tcpdump (`sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -s 1500 port not 22`) to ensure that google is not returning data form an ephemeral port. I've removed the extra data with the packet flags, and you can add `-X` to the flags to see the actual data in each packet.

```
18:28:56.919335 IP ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174 > prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http:
18:28:56.949105 IP prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http > ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174:
18:28:56.949119 IP ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174 > prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http:
18:28:56.949219 IP ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174 > prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http:
18:28:56.979089 IP prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http > ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174:
18:28:57.010155 IP prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http > ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174:
18:28:57.010178 IP ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174 > prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http:
18:28:57.010308 IP ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174 > prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http:
18:28:57.041100 IP prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http > ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174:
18:28:57.041110 IP ip-10-112-7-114.eu-west-1.compute.internal.40174 > prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net.http:
```

From there you can see that curl opened the port 40174 and google (prg03s06-in-f4.1e100.net) replied from port 80 (http in the log).

## Answer

Thanks to Tim and Michael-sqlbot. The answer is a bit buried in the comments. But the problem was a missunderstanding of how inbound rules work. The **port range** on the **inbound rules** refer to the **destination port**, not the source port. From the AWS docs

> The following are the parts of a network ACL rule:
>
> - Rule number. Rules are evaluated starting with the lowest numbered rule. As soon as a rule matches traffic, it's applied regardless of any higher-numbered rule that may contradict it.
> - Protocol. You can specify any protocol that has a standard protocol number. For more information, see Protocol Numbers. If you specify ICMP as the protocol, you can specify any or all of the ICMP types and codes.
> - [Inbound rules only] The **source of the traffic** (CIDR range) and **the destination (listening) port or port range**.
> - [Outbound rules only] The destination for the traffic (CIDR range) and the destination port or port range.
> - Choice of ALLOW or DENY for the specified traffic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make a connection on port 80 (or to any daemon on any port) the connection is handed off to high range port to keep port 80 free to accept new connections. These are called [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

You need to allow incoming traffic to these high range ports, which according to Wikipedia are 32768 to 61000. If you're providing a web server you probably need to allow them outgoing as well - which you have as rule 100.

**Update / expanded**
NACLs are stateless, which means you need to allow ports in each direction data needs to flow. When you connect to a web server on port 80 their web server says "connection accepted, continue this exchange on port (say) 50000". This is why you need to allow high range ports incoming to allow outgoing traffic.

There's another explanation [here](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/19157/ephemeral-port).

Comment: Thanks for you answer Tim. The problem I have is related to outgoing connections to port 80 and 443 (and I think in particular with the rule `1000`), not with the incoming traffic. If I understand correctly, when I do a `curl www.google.com` from one of the servers, curl opens an ephemeral port. That request goes from the server, passes the `Security Groups` but then the NACL stops the traffic. I don't fully understand why the NACL is stopping the traffic when rule `1000` says to accept all traffic coming from the VPC on all ephemeral ports.

Comment: @Augusto read my expanded answer. I believe my answer is still accurate. If you still don't understand please read up on how ephemeral ports work, it may explain it better than I can.

Comment: @Tim while you're correct, inbound access to the ephemeral ports is needed, it isn't for the reason stated.  When you make an *outbound* connection, let's say to a web server, you don't use *your* port 80 at all.  The connection begins and remains with one of your ephemeral ports as the source port, which is where the remote systems sends its responses, thus the ephemeral ports must be open to the world, or response traffic is discarded.  Network ACLs filter operate on *destination* ports and for the (inbound) reply traffic, you are the destination.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That sounds like more or less what I said, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Hi Tim, I don't think what you described is correct for HTTP (it's in the case of active FTP connections when transferring files). Ephemeral ports are only used by clients in HTTP. In TCP the 4-tuple source IP, source port, destination IP and destination port makes a connection unique, so the HTTP server doesn't need to delegate the connection to an ephemeral port.

Comment: @Augusto this is how HTTP works. According to Wikipedia it's for IP based protocols, anything using TCP/UDP, including ftp, ssh, etc. My answer also explains why opening ports as you described works. I'm unsure why you're resisting this answer. More info here, and perhaps wider reading would be useful for you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65475/ephemeral-port-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm just trying to understand why it's not working. I've re-read the wiki page and the other question and all so far looks like it matches my understanding. I've added a `tcpdump` of a curl to google to show that google doesn't reply from a ephemeral port, but from port 80. I re-read the AWS page on ephemeral ports and I found it confusing (but it does say to open ephemeral ports on both directions)... I'm still curious about thy *why*, rather than how to fix it... and I hope we can both learn something form this :).

Comment: I wonder if it's just the way tcpdump shows the data? I think my answer is correct but I think the explaination might need to come from someone else. @Michael-sqlbot?

Comment: @Augusto, here's what's being overlooked: Inbound network ACLs are only interested in the *source address* and *target port* -- not target address, not source port, so for internally-initiated connections, the port you are matching is the *remote* port (80) in the outbound direction (outbound NACL), but is the *local* port (ephemeral) for the inbound responses (inbound NACL).  Inbound, the NACL has to allow access *to* the ephemeral port, *from* everywhere, because that's where the taffic is headed towards.  Inbound NACL is not interested in the port the packet is *from*.

Comment: I've read that explanation four times, and I think I get it. Thanks @Michael-sqlbot :)

Comment: Yeah, my explanation gets a little bit fuzzy somewhere in the middle... sort of reminds me of [this](https://youtu.be/6e1hZGDaqIw). Inbound network ACLs aren't interested in the source port or the destination address.  For google (or whoever) port 80 to respond back to a connection initiated from one of my ephemeral ports, my inbound network ACL must allow access to my ephemeral port range, from source address 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim and Michael-sqlbot!!! I read that statement on the AWS docs and my brain didn't register it (*[Inbound rules only] The source of the traffic (CIDR range) and the destination (listening) port or port range.*). And thanks again @Tim for not giving up on me!

Answer (score 0):

if I have read the question correctly, when you change the Inbound Rule 1000 to 0.0.0.0/0 instead of 10.0.0.0/16 then connections from your EC2 instances to the internet work. I think this makes a bit of sense to me.

when traffic comes Inbound and is passed by the NACL (associated with the Subnet your Instances are on) the source is not the 10.0.0.0/16 subnet but it is whichever IP address is on the web service you have connected to. this is why 0.0.0.0/0 works and 10.0.0.0/16 doesn't

Comment: Hi Michael, I still don't fully understand why the NACL is blocking the traffic. I've updated my question with what I think happens (and why it should allow the traffic). Could you check it once more? Thanks!